# Single provider that creates different types of object based on class binding

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to inject several `datastax` `Mapper`s but the `Provider` creation code is always the same and writing a provider for each type is redundant.

The provider code is

```
public class FooMapperProvider extends Provider<Mapper<Foo>> () {
    private final MappingManager mappingManager

    @Inject
    FooMapperProvider(MappingManager) {
        this.mappingManager = mappingManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Mapper<Foo> get() {
        mappingManager.mapper(Foo.class);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to bind or create the provider for

```
bind(Foo.class).toProvider(GenericMapperProvider.class)
bind(Bar.class).toProvider(GenericMapperProvider.class)
```

so that `get` is called in a way `mappingManager.mapper` can create a mapper based on the class for that specific binding?

I thought about trying something like

```
public class MapperProvider<T> implements Provider<Mapper<T>> {
    private final MappingManager mappingManager;
    private final Class klass;

    @Inject
    public MapperProvider(MappingManager mappingManager, Class klass) {
        this.mappingManager = mappingManager;
        this.klass = klass;
    }

    @Override
    public Mapper<T> get() {
        return mappingManager.mapper(klass);
    }
}
```

but I can't figure out how to specify the class *and* inject the dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MapperProvider<T> implements Provider<Mapper<T>> {
    private final MappingManager mappingManager;
    private final TypeLiteral<T> type;

    @Inject
    public MapperProvider(MappingManager mappingManager, TypeLiteral<T> type) {
        this.mappingManager = mappingManager;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Mapper<T> get() {
        return mappingManager.mapper(type.getRawType());
    }
}

bind(new TypeLiteral<Mapper<Foo>>(){})
       .toProvider(new TypeLiteral<MapperProvider<Foo>>(){});
```